# Python manage.py Tatsu errors

Tags: python, collectstatic

Trying to run `python manage.py collectstatic` or any other `manage.py` command from the command line gives a dizzying array of Tatsu errors.

manage.py

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "freeform.settings.dev")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

errors:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 794, in _option
    yield
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 94, in block6
    self._rule_()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return self._call(ruleinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 609, in _call
    result = self._recursive_call(ruleinfo)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 640, in _recursive_call
    return self._invoke_rule(ruleinfo, key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 688, in _invoke_rule
    ruleinfo.impl(self)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 406, in _rule_
    self._expre_()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return self._call(ruleinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 609, in _call
    result = self._recursive_call(ruleinfo)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 640, in _recursive_call
    return self._invoke_rule(ruleinfo, key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 688, in _invoke_rule
    ruleinfo.impl(self)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 490, in _expre_
    self._error(
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 545, in _error
    raise self._make_exception(item, exclass=exclass)
tatsu.exceptions.FailedParse: (6:14) expecting one of: '|' <choice> <element> <option><sequence> :
ALPHADIGIT = ? "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
             ^
expre
rule
grammar
start

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 241, in parse
    return rule()
           ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return self._call(ruleinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 609, in _call
    result = self._recursive_call(ruleinfo)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 640, in _recursive_call
    return self._invoke_rule(ruleinfo, key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 688, in _invoke_rule
    ruleinfo.impl(self)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 68, in _start_
    self._grammar_()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return self._call(ruleinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 609, in _call
    result = self._recursive_call(ruleinfo)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 640, in _recursive_call
    return self._invoke_rule(ruleinfo, key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 688, in _invoke_rule
    ruleinfo.impl(self)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 103, in _grammar_
    self._closure(block6)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 883, in _closure
    block()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 93, in block6
    with self._option():
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 800, in _option
    raise FailedCut(e) from e
tatsu.exceptions.FailedCut: (6:14) expecting one of: '|' <choice> <element> <option><sequence> :
ALPHADIGIT = ? "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
             ^
expre
rule
grammar
start

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dir/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/dir/events/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ics
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .alarm import AudioAlarm, DisplayAlarm
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/alarm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ics.alarm.audio import AudioAlarm
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/alarm/audio.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ics.alarm.base import BaseAlarm
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/alarm/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ics.component import Component
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/component.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ics.grammar.parse import Container
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ics/grammar/parse.py", line 10, in <module>
    GRAMMAR = tatsu.compile(fd.read())
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/tool.py", line 184, in compile
    model = cache[key] = gen.parse(grammar, config=config, **settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 244, in parse
    raise self._furthest_exception from e
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 794, in _option
    yield
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 1175, in _regex_
    self._STRING_()
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 77, in wrapper
    return self._call(ruleinfo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 609, in _call
    result = self._recursive_call(ruleinfo)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 640, in _recursive_call
    return self._invoke_rule(ruleinfo, key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 688, in _invoke_rule
    ruleinfo.impl(self)
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/bootstrap.py", line 1112, in _STRING_
    self._error(
  File "/Users/dir/deployment/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tatsu/contexts.py", line 545, in _error
    raise self._make_exception(item, exclass=exclass)
tatsu.exceptions.FailedParse: (6:15) expecting one of: "((?:[^"\n]|\"|\\)*?)"'((?:[^'\n]|\'|\\)*?)' :
ALPHADIGIT = ? "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
              ^
STRING
regex
regexes
pattern
separator
gather
term
element
sequence
option
choice
expre
rule
grammar
start
```

I feel like this is maybe a library version mismatch issue?